# Subclassing UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I see this topic is discussed elsewhere but I don't see an answer to my questions.

I subclassed UIView to create a custom view. Currently I'm using interface builder to create a UIView and then setting the custom class option to my subclass.

First question. When I do that, how to I reference that instance from my code? I have a public function I would like to call that updates my view but I don't know how to call it from my view controller

Second question. I created an instance of the class from within my view controller just playing around and I noticed the public function I created isn't available with that instance. Can I create public functions when I inherit from UIView?

Comment: You need to update your question with relevant code and clearly show where your questions are with the code.

Comment: My first question is more about interface builder. I don't have any code to show for that. I think the second question will answer its self with the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to do:

1)subclass `UIView` to create `CustomView`, add your public `function`,in your project:

```
import UIKit

class CunstomView: UIView {

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

public func printHello() {


    print("hello")
}
}
```

2)In your `storyboard`, drag a `UIView` into your `vc`, and set the class to `CunstomView`, you can see that in my red frame:

[image: drag <code>UIView</code>]

3)click the `Show the Assistant Editor`, and ctrl-drag the `view` to the `vc`, set the name `custom`:

[image]

4)then in your `vc`'s `viewDidload` function, you call the public function:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var custom: CunstomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        custom.printHello()
    }


}
```

5)the result:

[image: the result]

Comment: Good, comprehensive answer. (Voted)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. As I suspected, this answered the second question as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your view from IB with the mothod below.

Objective-C:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    //do something
}
```

Swift

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
```

Second question

Do you mean the custom view don't answer the function you create within the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

> First question. When I do that, how to I reference that instance from
>   my code? I have a public function I would like to call that updates my
>   view but I don't know how to call it from my view controller

A: A view cannot exist by itself in app. You need viewcontroller to handle the custom view. Then in that VC, you can refer the view as IBOutlet.

> Second question. I created an instance of the class from within my
>   view controller just playing around and I noticed the public function
>   I created isn't available with that instance. Can I create public
>   functions when I inherit from UIView?

A: You can create public function of custom view, just declare them in the header file. Then import the header in your VC. Then u can access it.